# trying to get current value of dropdown menu in C# using Selenium

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code setup which works as expected to go through a webpage options for reports.  I would now like to pull the values of the of each web element after I click submit so I can then use that to send to a SQL query.  I am currently stuck on getting the values pulled from the current state of the webpage.

As you can see I am pulling from dropdowns by index #.  Please be kind I have only been working with C# and selenium for about a month.....

```
Open_TM_DD_URT();
        WAIT();
        var EntryType_URT = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("entryTypeDropdown"));
        var selectElement_URT = new SelectElement(EntryType_URT);
        WAIT();
        selectElement_URT.SelectByIndex(2);
        WAIT();

        var FiscalYear = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("fiscalYearsDropdown"));
        var Fiscal_Select = new SelectElement(FiscalYear);

        var BEC = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("businessEventCodesDropdown"));
        var BEC_Code = new SelectElement(BEC);

        SLEEP();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            Fiscal_Select.SelectByIndex(i);
            WAIT();
            SLEEP();
            for (int b = 1; b <= 53; b++)
            {
                BEC_Code.SelectByIndex(b);
                WAIT();
                SLEEP();
                HIT_SUBMIT_BTN();
                SLEEP();

                //this is where i need to get value of the two drop menus
```

this is the HTML i'm pulling from.

```
    <select _ngcontent-c8="" class="form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty" id="fiscalYearsDropdown" name="fiscalYearsDropdown" ng-reflect-name="fiscalYearsDropdown" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-model="2019">
                    <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
    }-->
                    <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
    }--><option _ngcontent-c8="" value="-1" ng-reflect-value="-1" class="ng-star-inserted">Select Fiscal Year</option>
                    <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "2019,2018,2017,2016,2015,2014,"
    }--><option _ngcontent-c8="" value="2019" ng-reflect-value="2019" class="ng-star-inserted">2019</option>
<option _ngcontent-c8="" value="2018" ng-reflect-value="2018" class="ng-star-inserted">2018</option>
<option _ngcontent-c8="" value="2017" ng-reflect-value="2017" class="ng-star-inserted">2017</option>
<option _ngcontent-c8="" value="2016" ng-reflect-value="2016" class="ng-star-inserted">2016</option>
<option _ngcontent-c8="" value="2015" ng-reflect-value="2015" class="ng-star-inserted">2015</option>
<option _ngcontent-c8="" value="2014" ng-reflect-value="2014" class="ng-star-inserted">2014</option>
<option _ngcontent-c8="" value="2013" ng-reflect-value="2013" class="ng-star-inserted">2013</option>
<option _ngcontent-c8="" value="2012" ng-reflect-value="2012" class="ng-star-inserted">2012</option>
<option _ngcontent-c8="" value="2011" ng-reflect-value="2011" class="ng-star-inserted">2011</option>
<option _ngcontent-c8="" value="2010" ng-reflect-value="2010" class="ng-star-inserted">2010</option>
<option _ngcontent-c8="" value="2009" ng-reflect-value="2009" class="ng-star-inserted">2009</option>
```

Comment: Please add html in text format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option has the attribute "value" and visible text, which in your example are equal, but can be different. You can use any code below.

To get text of selected option:

```
var fiscalSectedText = Fiscal_Select.SelectedOption.Text;
```

To get value attribute of selected option:

```
var fiscalSelectedValue = Fiscal_Select.SelectedOption.GetAttribute("value")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I think I may be missing something at the top of my code involving the "using...."   since I do not have a definition for "GetFirstSelectedOption"   Or I could be talking out of A** and have no idea

Comment: Awesome looks like that should work! thanks!! I knew I was on the right path but was missing some key pieces.